# Tomcat goes hang even in 100 concurrent request

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

I have deployed a big size war (600 mb) on the tomcat server. Its a great project and hence the number of users. But if counting it should not be more than 100 at a time. But my tomcat goes hang out even in this small number. The problem is server machine configuration, i can say its a ordinary developer machine with 2GB Ram and Core 2 duo processor. But i think it should be fine for handling at-least 100-200 concurrent request? Can you please suggest me any solution rather than upgrading server machine configuration. I know stack expertise will definitely help me.

And yes! i have taken care for the opened connections and code styling.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: are you sure it didn't throw an `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: @asgs, no it doesn't throw any OutOfMemmoryError, and its working very fine in normal cases but when number of user increases it starts creating problem.

Comment: @Eddy, :) Is that so? there is no other solution rather than upgrading server configuration.

Comment: I would start by checking the logs for exceptions.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your app and configuration, I'd just suggest you to profile the app and see when and why it's not responding.

Comment: again there is no exceptions in logs, i have checked it throughly.

Comment: @R.Rahul what is your solution then? I also facing the same problem.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution at that time and then I got busy with other important things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profile it! [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/). I'm sure you will find the answer.

Comment: i was not aware of this, i w'll try this and mark your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. check `maxThreads` and `acceptCount` settings in server.xml: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation
2. send it `kill -3` signal (`Ctrl-Break` on Windows) and analyze the thread dump (probably in catalina.out)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of concurrent usage.

If you are thinking about serving 100 requests at any moment, and assume one request takes 1 second to finish on average, that is 260 million hits per month. In comparison, Stackoverflow.com has 95 million page views per month. I doubt it's hosted on one PC.

It would still be an interesting question, why can't Stackoverflow.com be hosted on one PC? It doesn't seem impossible technically. But economically hosting cost is very tiny compared to the dev cost.

Answer (score 0):

600MB war, might have surely some static content, try to serve them from Apache webserver., You can use Apache - Tomcat load balancing technique.

Secondly, try to increase heap memory allocated tomcat JVM, it might help !